# Convert string to any object

Tags: java, string, dynamic, groovy, casting

I'm wondering on how to convert a string to any data type dynamically.
Example, I have these:

```
String dataType
String value
```

Then, these fields will be populated from the database.

```
dataType = "java.lang.Integer"
value = "42"
```

So, I want is to convert `"42" (String)` to `42 (int)`

I have solutions in mind:

1. Use [Class.cast(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29)
2. Switch for every data type, and use an according parse method.
   ex: `Integer.parseInt(String)` or `new BigDecimal(String)`
3. Use reflection methods for casting.

Any ideas guys?

(I won't be using external libraries)

Also, Groovy solutions are accepted.

Comment: Means you want to know which one is more proper and efficient?

Comment: `Class.cast(Object)` does *not* do conversions. The simplest solution is to use reflection to handle as many cases as possible but prepend a switch-based non-reflective conversion to accelerate *common* cases.

Comment: @user2173681 - yes, i want to know which is efficient

Comment: @Holger - yeah, i though so that the `cast` method cant do it. And yeah, maybe i'll consider reflecting and switches

Comment: Creating objects via reflection is not a difficult thing (given a parameterless constructor). The difficult job is putting the value into the object. There are so many ways: There could be a constructor taking a value. There could be a setter. There could be a parsing factory method. Sometimes you must parse first, then provide a more specialized object to your created or yet-to-create object. There is nothing that can do this all in a common, dynamic way.

Comment: As said, `cast` can’t do it. The code has to look like either `Class.forName(dataType).getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, value);` or `Class.forName(dataType).getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(value);`. Most value types support either style or even both.

Comment: that's a good solution @Holger! i'll implement that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Groovy you can use the `as` operator:

```
assert "42" as Integer == 42

assert 42 as String == "42"

assert 42 as Long == 42l

assert "42" as BigDecimal == 42.0
```

Comment: Its the first time I saw that keyword. I look it up [here](http://silvanolte.com/blog/2011/03/11/the-groovy-as-keyword/), and its really nice, and shorter than reflective casting.